# automapper: generate condition by naming convention

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

could you please help me in a little bit. Can't find a way of how to update automapper conventions or any other configurations in order to achieve following.

Let's say I have a such classes:

```
public class A
{
     public bool PropertyUpdated {get;set;}
     public int PropertyValue {get;set;}
}
```

and:

```
public class B
{
   public int PropertyValue {get;set;}
}
```

can I somehow have following map generated automatially (by naming convensions or so)

```
CreateMap<A,B>()
.ForMember(b => b.PropertyValue, mm => 
{
    mm.Condition(a => a.PropertyUpdated);
    mm.MapFrom(a => a.PropertyValue);
});
```

I have a tons of such properties and do not want to write such rules by myself. Just wondering if there's a way to tell automapper that I would like to use some convensional conditions.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: ForAllPropertyMaps would help.

Answer (score 0):

thanks @Lucian, it does the trick.

```
ForAllPropertyMaps(pm => !pm.SourceMember.Name.EndsWith("Updated"), (pm, ce) =>
            {
                var sourceType = pm.TypeMap.SourceType;
                var conditionPropertyName = $"{pm.SourceMember.Name}Specified";
                var property = sourceType.GetProperty(conditionPropertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
                if (property == null) return;


                var conditionParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(object));
                var parameterConvertion = Expression.Convert(conditionParameter, sourceType);
                var getPropertyValue = Expression.Property(parameterConvertion, conditionPropertyName);
                var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object, bool>>(getPropertyValue, conditionParameter);
                ce.Condition(lambda.Compile());
            });
```